# Взаимодействие div и mod

Tags: pascal

Как работают функции `DIV` и `MOD` в Паскале, когда они записаны в одной строчке?

Например:

```
b:=23;   
a:=b div 10 mod 10;
```

Как это работает и как вычисляется? Ведь переменной `а` присваивается одно число.
Присваивается результат `div` и `mod`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

`div` и `mod` - это такие же математические операторы, как `+`, `-`, `*` и т. д. Попробуйте вместо операторов `div` и `mod` представить какие-нибудь другие математические операторы, например, `+` и `-`, и всё сразу станет понятным.

```
a := b div 10 mod 10;
```

в нашем мысленном эксперименте превратится в

```
a := b + 10 - 10;
```

Что происходит в таком случае? Правильно, сначала вычисляется `b + 10`, затем от результата вычисления отнимается 10. Аналогично с `div` и `mod`: сначала вычисляется `b div 10`, затем - `(b div 10) mod 10`.

Учтите, что подобная замена применима только для операторов, [имеющих одинаковый приоритет](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_operators_precedence.htm) (`div` и `mod` имеют). Если бы выражение включало другие операторы с более высоким или низким приоритетом, порядок вычислений был бы другим (тут можно проводить аналогии, например, с умножением и сложением).

Answer (score 3):

Это работает последовательно. Сначала вычисляется `b div 10` (в результате имеем `2`), затем вычисляется `(b div 10) mod 10`, то есть `2 mod 10`. В результате получаем `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вычисляется результат операции `div`. Затем к результату `div` применяется `mod`.